# C++ unmanaged DLL in c#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke

I've been asked to intergrate webcam ZoneTrigger in my project. The SDK provided in the site is C++ also the sample. I've been able to get few functions to work. the place i've been stuck is a function where char* is a parameter passed. I did a lot of digging and have come to know that MarshalAs has to be used...

the function i'd like to import from
c++ code

```
//header file
struct ZT_TRIG_STRUCT 
{
int aSize;      //STRUCT size
int CameraIndex;
int SpotIndex;
int SpotType;
char SpotName[32];
DWORD Dummy[16];
};

typedef int (WINAPI *f_ZT_EnumerateHotSpots)(int SpotIndex, char *Name, int *SpotType);
/*
You application can call this functions to retrieve information about spots by iterating the SpotIndex param.
Name is a pointer to a 32 byte buffer supplied by your application.
SpotType is a pointer to an 32 bit integer in your application.
Return value:
0 = Success, the Name and SpotType have been initialized
1 = Error, we have lost communication with Zone Trigger
2 = Enumaration is over, all spots have been enumerated. Your application should increment SpotIndex until this function returns 2.
*/

//code
//Enumerate current spots in Zone Trigger
int i=0;
char SpotName[32];
int SpotType;
check = ZT_EnumerateHotSpots(i, SpotName, &SpotType);
while (check == 0) 
{
    float sensitivity = ZT_GetSensitivity(i);
    printf("Zone Trigger spot: %s   Sensitivity: %0.1f%%\r\n", SpotName,     sensitivity*100);
    check = ZT_EnumerateHotSpots(++i, SpotName, &SpotType);
}
```

So when converting to c#

```
[DllImport("ZTcom.dll")]
    private static extern int ZT_EnumerateHotSpots(int i, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]ref string SpotName, ref int SpotType);

 public unsafe struct ZT_TRIG_STRUCT 
    {
        public int aSize;       //STRUCT size
        public int CameraIndex;
        public int SpotIndex;
        public int SpotType;
      public string SpotName ;  
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 256)] string SpotName;
       // public IntPtr SpotName;
    }

//In code
int i = 0;
 string SpotName;
int SpotType;
check = ZT_EnumerateHotSpots(i, ref SpotName, ref SpotType);
```

the above line gives:

```
Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown.
```

ERROR.

i know that the problem is in SpotName,Its a byte[32], if i dont use marshalAs,instead i use just char it works n gives the first char..
the code where it works fine n gives first char is below

```
 public unsafe struct ZT_TRIG_STRUCT 
    {
        public int aSize;       //STRUCT size
        public int CameraIndex;
        public int SpotIndex;
        public int SpotType;
      public char SpotName ;              
    }

 [DllImport("ZTcom.dll")]
    private static extern int ZT_EnumerateHotSpots(int i, ref char SpotName, ref int SpotType);

 public char SpotName;
int i = 0;
            check = ZT_EnumerateHotSpots(i, ref SpotName, ref SpotType);
            while (check == 0)
            {
                float sensitivity = ZT_GetSensitivity(i);
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "\r\n" +"Zone Trigger spot: " + SpotName + "   Sensitivity: " + (sensitivity * 100).ToString();
                check = ZT_EnumerateHotSpots(++i, ref SpotName, ref SpotType);
            }
```

but if i put char[] it gives

```
Method's type signature is not Interop compatible. ERROR
```

i've run out of options here.... where have i gone wrong? should i use MarshalAs or char[]???
please help.....
thanks in Advance....

Comment: Why is the `ZT_TRIG_STRUCT` marked unsafe? It contains no unsafe members.

Comment: [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 32)] string SpotName; doesn't work?

Comment: @Preet Inline strings should use `UnmanagedType.ByValTStr`, not `LPStr`; see my answer.

Comment: ZT_TRIG_STRUCT is the struct used in other function also contains the data of the cam,trigger that we have to enumerate using the above function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see where you are using `ZT_TRIG_STRUCT`, but that should be declared like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct ZT_TRIG_STRUCT 
{
    public int aSize;
    public int CameraIndex;
    public int SpotIndex;
    public int SpotType;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=32)]
    public string SpotName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=16)]
    public uint[] Dummy;
}
```

The other problem you have is in the declaration of `ZT_EnumerateHotSpots`. That should be:

```
[DllImport("ZTcom.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern int ZT_EnumerateHotSpots(
    int SpotIndex, 
    StringBuilder SpotName, 
    out int SpotType
);
```

As I read it, `SpotName` is actually an out parameter, i.e. you supply a buffer and `ZT_EnumerateHotSpots` writes to it.

You then call this like so

```
int SpotIndex = 0;
StringBuilder SpotName = new StringBuilder(32);
int SpotType;
int result = ZT_EnumerateHotSpots(SpotIndex, SpotName, out SpotType);
```

Comment: Yep, you're right about the name being an out parameter and needing a StringBuilder. I didn't spot that, pun intended ;). I deleted my answer and upvoted yours.

Comment: @Sven Thanks. The other minor issue with your answer is that `DWORD` maps to `uint`.

Comment: They're the same size, and since the member is called `Dummy`, I doubt it really matters. :)